# [kapp-controller][carvel]How to update pod to reflect ConfigMap change using Kapp-Controller?

Tags: kubernetes, kapp-controller

I am using [kapp-controller](https://carvel.dev/kapp-controller/docs/v0.40.0/) to manage my application on a `Kubernetes` cluster.
What I want is that once `configmap`, which my deployment uses, changes then the corresponding pod should be able to see the updated `configmap`.

How to achieve this if `configmap` is

1. mounted as volume
2. using data of `configmap` as env variable

Answer (score 0):

https://carvel.dev/kapp/docs/v0.52.0/diff/#versioned-resources This URL describes with example how to consume `configmap` changes in the pod as the environment var.

If a `configmap` is mounted as a volume on a pod then up to date `configmap` will reflect don't pod's volume.